# merge four columns and two pairs in this way

Tags: tables

[image]

Is it possible to have tabular like this? Can you help?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (But it is not recommended.)

Comment: Try the `tabularray` package. You will only need to merge the cells in the top row. You can easily skip the horizontal lines between rows 3 and 6 without needing to merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` to merge cells and `\cline` to create horizontal lines spanning particular columns. The following example should generate the desired table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{thermal stability}\\ \cline{2-5}
{} & calcium hydroxide    & barium hydroxide  & calcium carbonate & barium carbonate\\ \hline
\textbf{A}   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{B}   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher\\ 
\textbf{C}   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{D}   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an image of your result to your answer?

Comment: I took a liberty and add image of table produced by your MWE.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Here are four ways to typeset the table. Compare them and take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\section{Best} % George

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{thermal stability}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& \ch{Ca(OH)2}   & \ch{Ba(OH)2} & \ch{CaCO3} & \ch{BaCO3} \\
\midrule
\textbf{A}   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{B}   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher\\ 
\textbf{C}   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{D}   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\section{Good} % Clint Eastwood

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{thermal stability}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& calcium & barium & calcium & barium \\
& hydroxide & hydroxide & carbonate & carbonate \\
\midrule
\textbf{A}   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{B}   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher\\
\textbf{C}   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{D}   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\section{Bad} % Lee Van Cleef

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{thermal stability}\\
\cline{2-5}
& calcium & barium & calcium & barium \\
& hydroxide & hydroxide & carbonate & carbonate \\
\hline
\textbf{A}   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{B}   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher\\
\textbf{C}   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{D}   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\section{Ugly} % Eli Wallach

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{solubility} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{thermal stability}\\
\cline{2-5}
& calcium hydroxide & barium hydroxide & calcium carbonate & barium carbonate \\
\hline
\textbf{A}   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{B}   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher\\
\textbf{C}   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower\\
\textbf{D}   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two solution ("good" an "ugly" from @egreg answer) with use of the `tabularray` and `booktabs` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
            colspec = { Q[c, font=\bfseries] *{4}{Q[c]} },
            cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
            cell{1}{even} = {c=2}{},
            }
    \toprule
    & solubility  
                &           & thermal stability  
                                        &                   \\ 
    \midrule
    & calcium hydroxide     
                & barium hydroxide  
                            & calcium carbonate 
                                        & barium carbonate  \\
    \midrule
A   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower             \\
B   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher            \\
C   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower             \\
D   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher            \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { Q[c, font=\bfseries] *{4}{Q[c]} },
             cell{1}{even} = {c=2}{},
            }
    \toprule
    & solubility
                &           & thermal stability
                                        &           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    & {calcium\\ hydroxide}
                & {barium\\ hydroxide}
                            & {calcium\\ carbonate}
                                        & {barium\\ carbonate}  \\
    \midrule
A   & higher    & lower     & higher    & lower     \\
B   & higher    & lower     & lower     & higher    \\
C   & lower     & higher    & higher    & lower     \\
D   & lower     & higher    & lower     & higher    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]